# Print whole expanded Main Menu in page.tpl.php / menu block

Tags: blocks, navigation

I am looking for a way to use `drupal_render()` to show the entire expanded main menu.
Right now I am using this piece of code, but since I use the *Menu blocks* module from the third level on, all links from level 3 (and down) are missing here. Solution must be working with i18n, too.

```
if (module_exists('i18n_menu')) {
  $main_menu_tree = i18n_menu_translated_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
}
else {
  $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
}
print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
```

Any idea on how I can get all links shown?